# QUERY FOR NUMBERS IN MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте у меня такой вопрос ..есть одна таблица в котором есть число до 10 нужно писать query который нам дает все четные и нечетные числи

Comment: остаток от деления на 2 - `поле % 2`

Comment: типо так? SELECT * FROM sum WHERE number = ...  и здесь что писать

Comment: number % 2 = 0 или равен 1

Comment: спасибо огромное